# C#: How can I use brackets within quotes in json?

Tags: c#, json

I have this json-file:

```
{
    "TestString": "This is a \"{Test}\""
}
```

If it doesn't exist I auto-generate it.

For example, this is a C#-Code, where I use the string directly:

```
class Programm
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string s = "{ \"TestString\": \"This is a \"{test}\"\"}";

        Test test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Test>(s);
    }
}
```

Now the problem is, that the string doesn't work this way, because C# will make the quotes literal and then storing it in the `string s`, resulting in

```
"{ "TestString": "This is a "{test}""}"
```

which is a faulty json-string, cause the quotes are not escaped.

```
static void Main()
{
    string s = @"{ ""TestString"": ""This is a ""{test}""""}";

    Test test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Test>(s);
}
```

Making the entire string a literal results in the same.

Is there something I am missing out?

Comment: Do you mean how to escape the backslash itself? -> \\

Comment: That doesn't work, cause then the quote isn't escaped and c# thinks, that its the end of the string. And if i do \\"", that doesn't work either

Comment: You can just use the serialisation So you just have to handle the property value `"This is a \"{Test}\""` , like https://dotnetfiddle.net/UxJdyJ . I will not recommend hardcoding a Json into a C# variable. Either use an object serialisation or a real json file (text file)

Comment: "That doesn't work, cause then the quote isn't escaped" - that just means you haven't quoted the backslash properly. It would be `This is a \\\"{test}\\\"` within the string - `\\` is "escaped backslash" and `\"` is "escaped quote"

Comment: Use this: `@"{ ""TestString"": ""This is a \""{test}\"""" }"`. We need to escape the `"` in json string content with \

Comment: @OguzOzgul the solution is too tedious unlike mine and that of the others when in the case of another characters to be escaped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\"{test}\"` adds escaped quotes so that C# doesn't terminate the string but it does break the JSON. To escape the quotes in the JSON too you'll need to add an escaped back-slash `\\` and the JSON should be:

```
string s = "{ \"TestString\": \"This is a \\\"{test}\\\"\"}";
```

A better way to generate correct JSON is to serialise anonymous objects (unless you have appropriate models.

```
var model = new { TestString = "This is a \"{test}\""};
string s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
Test test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Test>(s);
```

**NOTE:** You could also use a Verbatim String

With verbatim strings a slash, is just a slash and isn't an escape character. To embed a quote use double double-quotes (`""`). Newlines are also preserved allowing you to easily create a multi-line string without some combination of carriage returns (`\r`) and line feeds (`\n`). They *can* often be easier to read - note the sequence of 4 double-quotes towards the end of the string.

```
    string s = @"{ ""TestString"": ""This is a \""{test}\""""}";
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a Json file your first go should be using an object serialisation It will remove the need for escaping char in a string variable.

```
//// Using an Object as input
var data = new Foo { TestString = "This is a \"{Test}\""};  
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(json);
result.Dump();      



File.WriteAllText("tempFile.txt", json);
////Using a txtFile
var inputFile = File.ReadAllText("tempFile.txt");
var resultFile = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(inputFile);
resultFile.Dump();
```

For verbatim string start from the string you expect: `"TestString": "This is a \"{Test}\""`
And add a DQuote before every DQuote => `""TestString"":""This is a \""{Test}\""""`

```
////Using a string verbatim @
var inputVerbatim  = @"{""TestString"":""This is a \""{Test}\""""}";
var resultVerbatim = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(inputVerbatim);
resultVerbatim.Dump();
```

For simple string you have to escape every special char with a `\`.
`"TestString": "This is a \"{Test}\""`
=>`\"TestString\":\"This is a \\\"{Test}\\\"\"`

```
////Using a simple string 
var inputString = "{\"TestString\":\"This is a \\\"{Test}\\\"\"}";
var resultString = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(inputString);
resultString.Dump();
```

[LiveDemo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LuEeHV)

Comment: "Using a string literal @" don't you mean verbatim string?

Comment: @snr-ReinstateMonica, Sorry I had many tabs open and was fighting some unformated code warning. what's the issue?

Comment: @phuzi, thx. I miss the term every time. In the spec the chapter is named String literal. "**String literals:**_C# supports two forms of string literals: regular string literals and verbatim string literals._", 4 times literal my brain only remember that part.

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question right, you just want to add some special character to your JSON string.
Just add them like this:

```
\"
```

or for Backslash :

```
\\
```

Comment: What I want is to write the " with C#. but no matter how I escape it, the JsonConvert always throws an error

Comment: Why did this answer get downvoted? This seems to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

The \" is used by C# to escape quotes, and also by JSON.  So this means that:

If you put this valid JSON text into a file:

```
{ 
    "TestString": "This is a \"{test}\""
}
```

And read it like this:

```
    string res = File.ReadAllText(@"c:\data\test.json");
    var t1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Test>(res);
```

Then it will be the same as entering the text in the string directly like this:

```
    string res2 = "{ \"TestString\": \"This is a \"{test}\"\"}";
    var t2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Test>(res);
```

And both will give you the output of

> This is a "{test}"

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the quotes around {test} are not being escaped properly. Try:

```
string s = "{ \"TestString\": \"This is a \\\"{test}\\\"\"}";
```